# Stability of sheaves of non-constant rank

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $E\to X$ be a coherent sheaf over a compact (projective) Kahler manifold. The definition of stability of sheaves as stated in Huybrechts-Lehn (Definition 1.2.12) says that $E$ is stable if for all subsheaf $F$ we have $\mu(F)< \mu(E)$ where $\mu$ denotes the slope
$$\mu(E)=\frac{\deg(E)}{rk(E)}.$$

My question is: Does this definition apply to sheaf of non constant rank? I would say yes since coherent sheaves of constant ranks are just vector bundles. But if the ranks varries (for example if the support of the sheaf does not have full dimension) does the slope varry too? If so the inequality of the slopes should be consider at every point in $X$?

Answer (score 2):

The rank of a coherent sheaf is defined as its rank at the general point (equivalently, as the rank on a dense open subset where the sheaf is locally free). So, yes, the definition applies.

Comment: So according to this definition a vector bundle (or coherent sheaf) supported on a subvariety has rank zero ?

Comment: Yes. Note that in the Definition you quote the condition on $F$ is $0<\operatorname{rk}(F)<\operatorname{rk}(E)  $.

Comment: @BinAcker In the quoted definition, the sheaf is also assumed to be pure, so it has no nontrivial subsheaves supported on a subvariety. A convention you sometimes see, which amounts to the same thing in practice, is to define the slope to be $+\infty$ if the generic rank is zero.